# AWS Kinesis Failed Sent cause

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

I'm using the KPL's addUserRecord to send Books. I want to:

1. Know when all books for a given author were actually processed (Need to update an audit table)
2. Log successes & failures for each book and its ISBN

I tried two things.

I created a Map of ISBN to the future object. Works fine for successes, but for failures, I'm not able to access the UserRecordResult object.

```
    Map<String,ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult>> sendResultFuturesMap = new HashMap<>();    
ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> resultFuture = producer.addUserRecord(kinesisStream, partitionKey, data);
sendResultFuturesMap.put(key, resultFuture);
...
// Verify
for(Map.Entry<String,ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult>> entry : sendResultFuturesMap.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> resultFuture = entry.getValue();
  UserRecordResult result = null;
  try {
    result = resultFuture.get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // I always get an ExecutionException that just says "com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException"
    // the if below is never executed, so I never get the UserRecordResult object
    if (e instanceof UserRecordFailedException) {
      result = ((UserRecordFailedException) e).getResult();
    }
  }
  
}
```

I tried the callback, and I'm able to get the UserRecordResult object for both success and fail, but I'm not sure how to link it to my ISBN.

```
ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> resultFuture = producer.addUserRecord(kinesisStream, partitionKey, data);
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(resultFuture, kinesisSentCallback, resultFutureThreadPool);

private static FutureCallback<UserRecordResult> kinesisSentCallback = new FutureCallback<>() {
  ...
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    //Works fine. I'm able to get the UserRecordResult object 
    if (t instanceof UserRecordFailedException) {
      UserRecordFailedException e = (UserRecordFailedException) t;
      UserRecordResult result = e.getResult();
      // How do I get ISBN from the result object?
    }
}
```

Should I be creating a new callback for each message? That seems inefficient. How do ppl do it?